# Publishing/ Documenting Spring-REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have looked around a bit on stackoverflow as well as google, but couldn't find any good tool that can document SPRING-REST api. Tried using enunciate, but it barfed out on spring annotations it couldn't recognize. Does anyone know of a good tool for documenting a spring RESTful api ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you need not document your REST API. Your clients should be provided with the specification of the media type you are using (think Atom or OpenSearch for example) and only rely on the information given there.

As soon as you document anything about a specific service, you are coupling your clients to that documentation (and that service). The result being that your service's ability to evolve is now limited by the amount of out-of-band information the clients have baked in their code (based on your API description).

IOW - when was the last time you needed a service API description to make your feed reader talk to an AtomPub service?

Jan

P.S. The theoretical backgrounds I summarized in [1]. Look specifically at the difference between HTTP Type I/II and REST. And Roy's [2] is a MustRead on this.

[1] http://www.nordsc.com/ext/classification_of_http_based_apis.html
[2] http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: unfortunately, that's a pretty pie-in-the-sky picture of a REST API.  most real world REST API's don't live in the happy theoretical world which Fielding originally described.

Comment: So then - how do these worlds differ? Any example?

Comment: the biggest thing i've seen is that with REST apis to be consumed by programs, you don't drive relationships off of links.  you are generally writing code which already has knowledge of the data structure (since you need to do something with the data), so you don't need to traverse relationships using urls provided by the service.  instead, objects have ids, and there are known urls to work with each object type, so it's simple url construction to work with the objects you need to work with.  plenty of other stuff, but that's the first one that came to mind.

Comment: Well - but there is really nothing that prevented a better design in the first place (which is I thought you were saying)?

Comment: You thought you said that most real world REST APIs live in environments that prevented them from being implemented RESTfully. (Apparently you simply meant that most real world REST APIs are not RESTful (which is unfortunately true).

Comment: I meant that most real world REST APIs are not RESTful _on purpose_ because that is the most "usable" form when working with them programatically.  in other words "truly RESTful" == "less convenient for programmatic consumption".

Comment: The whole distinction between human vs non-human, aka programmatically, is moot. Just doesn't exist. User Agents are just software programmed to step through an intended application based on what transitions they find. If they can't they can't. No amount of coupling is gonna help with that in networked environments. Besides, you should probably back up you assertion that "ruly RESTful" == "less convenient for programmatic consumption". Why do you think so?

Comment: i already explained one of the reasons above.  and yes, the difference does exist, although maybe i've chosen a poor term for the difference.  what i mean by "programmatic" is a program which consumes _and_ understands the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just document everything that needs to be documented from a client developer perspective. And please don't take advice like "you need not document your REST API" seriously. This is a pedantic guidance and not useful in the real world.

Every successful API out there is well documented from client developer point of view. Any API that is hung up on pedantic notions is bound to turn off client developers.

See Chapter 14 of my "RESTful Web Services Cookbook" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) for some examples.

Comment: Subbu, first, please do not confuse API documentation with describing what your service *is*. Surely, I need to know that something 'is a search service' before I can even decide that I want to talk to it. But this is at a completely different level than the technical description of how to interact with it. An entry URI and knowledge about the used media types is completely sufficient. As for your chapter 14: a service document (with the proper media type)  can very well remove the need for most of the things you list in your description recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Swagger. It provides few of its own annotation that work well with Spring MVC rest annotations.